# Returning data within MVC using jQuery AJAX to call APIController

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I have an MVC View called Index, and I want to return the data from a Car object.
I am using jQuery AJAX to call the data from an API Controller

Using postman I am able to get data back, but when debugging the view completely skips the ajax get call. I am not sure why I have json serialization as well as cors enabled in my apiconfig file so that shouldn't be an issue.

Any suggestions are much appreciated

MVC View:

```
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!DocType HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .dvdItem {
            height: 180px;
            width: 70%;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            background-color: lightgray;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 35px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
            -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
            box-shadow: -1px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
            padding: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="jumbotron well">
                    <h2>
                        Hello, world!
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#">Learn more</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="item-details" class="col-md-9"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        loadItems();
    });


    function loadItems() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Car/Featured',
            success: function (itemArray) {

                $.each(itemArray, function (index, Car) {
                    $('#item-details').append('<a onclick="GetItemId(' + Car.ReleaseYear + ')"><div id="item" class="dvdItem col-md-3"><p>' + Car.Model + '</p><p>' + Car.Make + '</p><p>$' + Car.Price.toFixed([2]) + '</p></div></a>');
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#errorMessages')
                    .append($('<li>')
                        .attr({ class: 'List-group-item list-group-item-danger' })
                        .text('Error'));
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The API Controller with the actions:

```
    using GuildCars.DAL;
using GuildCars.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Results;

namespace GuildCars.Controllers
{
    public class CarController : ApiController
    {
        CarRepository carRepository = new CarRepository();


        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("car/featured")]
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public IHttpActionResult Featured()
        {
            List<Car> found =  carRepository.GetFeatured();
            if (found == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(found);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are the missing quotes in `url: '/Car/Featured'` a typo?

Comment: You have no function called `loadItems()`.  JavaScript is case-sensitive.  Also, `url: /Car/Featured` is a syntax error.  Look at your browser's debugging console when debugging client-side code.

Answer (score 1):

You will not able to call the api function as url: '/Car/Featured' because it already handled by WebApiConfig. You need to call the function as

```
  url: 'api/Car/Featured'
```

The default Registration is usually found in WebApiConfig and tends to look like this

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
    // Attribute routing.
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // Convention-based routing.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
  }
}
```

You need to edit the routeTemplate in the convention-based setup.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
    // Attribute routing.
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // Convention-based routing.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use url as :

```
'Car/Featured'
```